# Result of initializer is unsued

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to enable a detailed view on tap as well as a swipe gesture to favorite the landmark. I cannot do the same using the navigation link so that any suggestions would be appreciated. I have both the applications attached below

```
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                Text("Favorites only")
            }
            ForEach(filteredLandmarks) { landmark in
                NavigationLink {
                    LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
                }
            label: {
                    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                }
            }
            
            */
            
            
            ForEach(filteredLandmarks){ landmark in
                LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                    .swipeActions(edge:.trailing){
                        Button{
                            print("fav")
                        } label:{
                            Label("favourite",systemImage: "star.circle.fill")
                        }
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        LandmarkDetail( landmark: landmark)
                    }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Landmarks")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't use `onTapGesture` to navigate to another `View`.

> Result of initializer is unused

is caused by using `onTapGesture` to navigate to another `View`.

Fortunately, there is a solution for your problem. Inside your second `ForEach` loop, replace your code with the code below.

```
NavigationLink {
    LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
} label: {
    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
}
.swipeActions(edge:.trailing){
    Button{
        print("fav")
    } label:{
        Label("favourite",systemImage: "star.circle.fill")
    }            
}
```